# Titanium Appcelerator : Application Error : Runtime Error: unknown Exception

Tags: windows-phone, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I am using :

```
System
    Name                        = Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
    Version                     = 10.0.10586
    Architecture                = 64bit
Titanium SDK  5.4.0.v20160601151241 (active)
    Version                   = 5.4.0
    Platforms                 = android, mobileweb, windows
    node-appc Version         = 0.2.35
Java Development Kit
    Version                     = 1.7.0_80
Microsoft (R) Visual Studio
  14.0 (selected)        
    CLR Version               = v4.0.30319
    MSBuild Version           = v14.0.25123.0    
Microsoft (R) Windows Phone SDK
    10.0
    8.1
Windows Phone Devices : Lumia 540 Dual SIM (RM-1141)
```

When I Run my widget that closes one window and initializes a controller to display another window, I get error :

```
Application Error
Runtime Error: unknown Exception    
Appcelerator When your app is packaged for final distribution, no error screen will appear.
```

Can someone please guide on where can I find the file for this error  so I can try-catch this error for better understanding or detail on this....
Also if someone can explain this error.

I found some reference at : https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile_windows/blob/master/Source/TitaniumKit/src/Application.cpp

But could not find this file to add logs in the file.

Answer (score 1):

I encounter the similar problem today morning! Only to find out 
"borderRadius : '5%'" was throwing the error.

```
`var _viewMask =  Ti.UI.createView({
    borderWidth:0,
    height : v2, 
    width: v2, borderRadius : '5%'
});`
```

You may have similar syntax which may not be valid & that is causing this type of error..

why not check this & solve it?

Comment: thanks kerobs.. I am aware of the fact that borderRadius  does not works in Windows Phone and I am not using this css attribute anywhere..the issue seems to be somewhere else